# UISwitch within UITableViewCell not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uiswitch, user-interaction

I have added a Prototype cell to my `UITableView` which has a `UISwitch` and an `UILabel`. When I run the app the UISwitch and UILabel display fine as expected, but some how I can not interact with the UISwitch. I can not toggle it between On or Off.

I have also tried creating a separate UITableViewCell and implementing the same UI. Still I have the same issue.

I am inflating the Cell as follows :-

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            RatingTableCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("RatingTableCell") as RatingTableCell;

            if (choiceList != null && choiceList.Count > 0)
            {
                cell.UpdateCellchoiceList.ElementAt(indexPath.Row));
            }
            else
            {
                //Do something else
            }



            return cell;
        }



 public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);


        }
```

**EDIT**

The whole cell is also not getting clicked. If I just add a label without the UISwitch the cell click works fine.

[image]

Comment: Have you set any properties like tableView.allowsSelection = false ?

Comment: @Bharath Nope. I haven't set anything like that

Comment: @Bharath Please check my edit

Comment: Do you have any other UIElements in the cell except the switch & label, If any other ui elements is upon the cell then it may not allow the action for below contents.

Comment: @Bharath I don't have any other elements

Comment: Please share some code on your "valueChanged" delegate method, didSelectRow & cellforRow method

Comment: @Bharath I have added code for didSelectRow and cellForRow methods. I haven't implemented the valueChanged method as I cannot interact with the switch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155803/discussion-between-bharath-and-user3034944).

Comment: The code provided in your question has no problem, please show all the code in Class RatingTableCell.cs

Answer (score 22):

In case someone comes to this post like me, this might be helpful. If your `UISwitch` is added manually to the `UITableViewCell`, make sure it's added to the `contentView` of the cell. The `UISwitch` will not work if it's added like `addSubview(switch)`, you need to do `contentView.addSubview(switch)` instead.

Comment: That's an issue on iOS 14+

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that selection and user interaction is enabled:
[image: Selection]
[image: User Interaction]

Comment: Hi. I have enabled the Single Selection and also the user interaction. But it still remains the same

Comment: ok, i guess you'll need to provide some more info on how you've added the UIElements and how they are implemented in your code.

Comment: I have just added a UITableView to my Storyboard ViewController. Then added a UISwitch and an UILabel to the prototype cell.

Comment: Please check my question as I haved added some more code